# How to resume the USB device after selective suspend configuration in Ubuntu host

Tags: ubuntu, usb, power-management, suspend, usb-device

I have Linux based development board on which DWC3 USB controller driver is present. I have implemented Link Power Management(L2 state) in the usb driver. Ubuntu is the host which on which my development board is connected via USB.

I need to perform regression testing of USB suspend-resume by using shell script. I have managed to write some portion of it,

```
**usb suspend-resume.sh**

path=1-10
echo auto > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/$path/power/control 
echo 10 > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/$path/power/autosuspend

sleep 10

iteration="10"
count="0"

while [ $count -lt $iteration ]
do
    rs=$(cat /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/$path/power/runtime_status)

    if [ "$rs" = "suspended" ]  
    then    
        echo usb is suspended
        sleep 5     
        count=$((count+1))
    fi
done
```

Devices on Ubuntu 14.04:
/dev/ttyACM0
/dev/ttyACM1
/dev/ttyACM2
/dev/ttyACM3

***The above script could perform only suspend(every 10s) but i'm not able to proceed how to resume the device.***

Answer (score 1):

To resume the suspended device

```
echo on > /sys/bus/usb/devices/$path/power/control
```

This should activate the suspended device. You can check for the state of the device using

```
cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/$path/power/runtime_status
```