# /dev/ttyACM0 not added upon resuming CentOS VM

Tags: udev, power-management, suspend, usb-device

I'm running CentOS v.7.5.1804, Kernel 3.10.0-862.el7.x86_64.

Host machine has a USB dongle mapped to `/dev/ttyACM0` on the guest VM.

Upon running `systemctl suspend` and resuming the VM, `/dev/ttyACM0` gets removed, however does not get added back. The only way I have at my disposal to get it back is to physically re-plug the dongle. Below is the listing of `udevadm monitor`.

Is it possible to get the dongle detected without physically replugging it?

I think solution to current question will also help solve [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/496165/how-to-resume-the-usb-device-after-selective-suspend-configuration-in-ubuntu-hos).

```
######## UDEV events when dongle gets unplugged #############
KERNEL[40020.994890] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.2/2-2.2:1.0/tty/ttyACM0 (tty)
KERNEL[40020.994919] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.2/2-2.2:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[40020.994929] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.2/2-2.2:1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[40020.995073] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.2 (usb)
UDEV  [40020.996954] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.2/2-2.2:1.0/tty/ttyACM0 (tty)
UDEV  [40020.997707] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.2/2-2.2:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [40020.998251] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.2/2-2.2:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [40020.998773] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.2 (usb)


######## UDEV events when dongle gets plugged back #############
KERNEL[40023.384021] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.2 (usb)
KERNEL[40023.417572] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.2/2-2.2:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[40023.419436] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.2/2-2.2:1.0/tty/ttyACM0 (tty)
KERNEL[40023.421406] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.2/2-2.2:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [40023.427400] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.2 (usb)
UDEV  [40023.428051] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.2/2-2.2:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [40023.428235] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.2/2-2.2:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [40023.430357] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.2/2-2.2:1.0/tty/ttyACM0 (tty)



####### VM is suspended and resumed here, /dev/ttyACM0 is removed but not added back############
KERNEL[40032.878071] remove   /devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck1 (machinecheck)
KERNEL[40032.878130] remove   /devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck2 (machinecheck)
KERNEL[40032.878140] remove   /devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck3 (machinecheck)
KERNEL[40032.878146] add      /devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck1 (machinecheck)
KERNEL[40032.878153] add      /devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck2 (machinecheck)
KERNEL[40032.878158] add      /devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck3 (machinecheck)
KERNEL[40032.878176] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.1/2-2.1:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/rfkill7 (rfkill)
KERNEL[40032.878183] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.1/2-2.1:1.0/bluetooth/hci0 (bluetooth)
KERNEL[40032.882785] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0f.0/drm/card0 (drm)
UDEV  [40032.896262] remove   /devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck1 (machinecheck)
KERNEL[40032.897736] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.2/2-2.2:1.0/tty/ttyACM0 (tty)
KERNEL[40032.897750] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.2/2-2.2:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[40032.897758] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.2/2-2.2:1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[40032.916152] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.2 (usb)
UDEV  [40032.916188] remove   /devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck2 (machinecheck)
UDEV  [40032.916238] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.1/2-2.1:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/rfkill7 (rfkill)
UDEV  [40032.916252] remove   /devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck3 (machinecheck)
UDEV  [40032.916264] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.1/2-2.1:1.0/bluetooth/hci0 (bluetooth)
UDEV  [40032.916273] add      /devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck3 (machinecheck)
UDEV  [40032.916281] add      /devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck2 (machinecheck)
UDEV  [40032.921414] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0f.0/drm/card0 (drm)
UDEV  [40032.921940] add      /devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck1 (machinecheck)
UDEV  [40032.931733] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.2/2-2.2:1.0/tty/ttyACM0 (tty)
UDEV  [40032.933373] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.2/2-2.2:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [40032.933398] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.2/2-2.2:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [40032.935702] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.2 (usb)
KERNEL[40032.940491] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.1/2-2.1:1.0/bluetooth/hci0 (bluetooth)
UDEV  [40032.940514] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.1/2-2.1:1.0/bluetooth/hci0 (bluetooth)
KERNEL[40032.940526] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.1/2-2.1:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/rfkill8 (rfkill)
UDEV  [40032.951063] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.1/2-2.1:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/rfkill8 (rfkill)
KERNEL[40034.139906] add      /kernel/slab/nf_conntrack_ffff9099a9dae680 (slab)
UDEV  [40034.140268] add      /kernel/slab/nf_conntrack_ffff9099a9dae680 (slab)
```

Comment: Just to be clear: are you saying that, if you *leave* the dongle plugged in, the device goes away, but you get it back if you unplug (disconnect) it and re-insert it?

Comment: That's correct: if I leave the device plugged in during the VM suspend/resume cycle, it doesn't show up under `/dev/ttyACM0` upon resume. The only way I can make it re-appear upon resume is to physically unplug and plug it back.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I still did not find the solution to the problem of dongle not appearing, but I made progress investigating it and realized I had posted the question in the wrong community: The dongle can be made re-appear without physically plugging it back by explicitly re-enabling it in the host machine's VMWare Fusion USB options. As such, it is VMWare Fusion that is responsible for the dongle not showing up upon resume, rather the guest CentOS VM.